# how to date convention in list and string?

Tags: python

I wrote a program that needs to translate a date format. If the date format is not entered correctly, then it will print an invalid format. It was not showing up.

```
from datetime import datetime
date_input = input('Please enter a date of form(mm/dd/yyyy): ')
date_object = datetime.strptime(date_input, '%m/%d/%Y')
date1 = datetime.strftime(date_input,'%m/%d')
if input == 'date_object':
    print(date_object.strftime('%B %d, %Y'))
elif input == date1:
 print('invaild date format')
```

I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: `if input == 'date_object':` - I don't know what you are trying to test here, but `input` is the name of a function, so you are testing whether a function equals a string. Your program has no output, because neither your `if` nor your `elif` conditions can ever be true.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
from datetime import datetime
try:
    date_input = input('Please enter a date of form(mm/dd/yyyy): ')
    date_object = datetime.strptime(date_input, '%m/%d/%Y')
except:
    print('invalid date format')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional is checking if your input is equal to the date_object you are creating (which is parsed to the format you are giving it in its second argument). Are you sure you want to do this ?(input is a function, not the string date_input) Also you check only 2 cases with this conditional statement, would it be better to check if your input is equal to the format you are evaluating and then in the else for that condition just print out the error message for any other case that isn't the one you want?

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_input  = input('Please enter a date of form(mm/dd/yyyy): ')
date_object = datetime.strptime(date_input, '%m/%d/%Y')

encoded_date_input = (str(date_object.month)).zfill(2) + '/' +(str(date_object.day)).zfill(2)+ '/' +str(date_object.year)
if encoded_date_input == date_input:
    print(date_object.strftime('%B %d, %Y'))
else:
    print('invaild date format')
```